# Assistance with WingIDE Linux download

Tags: linux

I am trying to download WingIDE for Kali linux but I am having trouble getting the terminal to initiate the download of WingIDE. I've downloaded the ubuntu/debian pckg and opened it into archive manager. When i try to start the download "dpkg -i wingide5_5.1.4-1_i386.deb" it tells there is no such file or directory. I am brand new to Linux, so please tell me what I am doing wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you wanting to write some code that accomplishes this? If so, then you should probably specify what language you prefer to work with. Otherwise, it's off-topic on a programming QA board...

Comment: @twalberg I think a question pertaining to the installation of an IDE is very appropriate for a programming QA, since it is an essential tool for programming. I need help installing this so I can continue my pentesting practice

Comment: I've extracted the WingIDE folders to the desktop, but the terminal is still telling me there is no such file or directory in existence. I should probably mention that I am running Kali Linux on a VM, which might be causing these complications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally realized what I was doing wrong. I was not navigating to the proper directory in Linux. When i finally cd'd to Desktop and punched in "ls", there was my compressed WingIDE file. I was able to unpackage it and successfully install it to my Kali Linux VM.